# HQL query for select fields from child entity class required for Jasper Report

Tags: hibernate, jasper-reports, hql

I need HQL query for **`Jasper Report`** to `select` child entity fields.

I tried following query in reoprt.jrxml:

```
select c.fullname, p.description from Client c inner join c.Product p
```

But I get:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean: description.

I know this query return two `Objects` but I don't know what is proper way to `select` child entity fields using HQL

Alternatively I tried put `Product` fields in `Map` and used these parameters in Jasper Report that works but it's not good practice.

```
Map map = new HashMap();
    manager.searchId(74).forEach(client -> {
    map.put("description", client.getProduct().getDescription());
});
```

Which query I should use?

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot create typed query for query with more than one return using requested result type

The message says it already, you have multiple query returns i.e. select items which can't use a result type other than `Object[]` or `Tuple`.

How is the below code different? You are still returning a `List<Client>`. You can return a list of map if you want by using a HQL feature like this:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> quotation() {
    try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
        return session.createQuery("select new map(c.fullname as fullname, p.description as description) from Client as c inner join Product p where c.id=74", Map.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, then just use `return session.createQuery("select new map(c.fullname as fullname, p.description as description) from Client as c inner join Product p where c.id=74", Map.class).getSingleResult();`

Comment: Sorry @ Christian Beikov I want get this query work in Jasper Repotrs but it doesn't. I want query for Jasper Reports.

Comment: Hi  I solved it, It doesn't have to write even query I just created field in Jasper Report product.description and it solved the problem.  And I have searched record using JPA instead HQl.